# Disable Caching in Laravel Ajax View Response

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, caching, laravel-5

I am currently using Laravel 5.3 and have a view whereby once a user navigates to that page.

The issue that I am experiencing is that my AJAX function works fine however when I then filter the user details again, I always get the previous response and not my new data...

I do an AJAX request to a controller function which returns a rendered view which is then set in my JavaScript like so:

```
    function loadUserDetails (selectedDetails)
    {
            $('#user-details-container').html("");

            var url = '{{ route('user.details') }}';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: {
                    details: selectedDetails,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var loadedHtml = data.html;
                    $('#user-details-container').html(loadedHtml);
                }
            });
    }
```

However then in my Laravel controller where I getUserDetails and actually render my view. I am setting my view up pretty normally however here is how I am trying to return my rendered view as a JSON response.

```
$returnHTML = view('user-details')->with('userDetails', $userOverview)->render();
    $headers = ['Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'];
    return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML), 200, $headers);
```

I am aiming to remove server side caching for this view as the user can do this request again with different parameters, I tried using header() but that didn't work...

```
  //set headers to NOT cache a page
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //HTTP 1.1
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

I am just wondering how would I remove the server side caching that Laravel is implementing on this route? As the user needs to be able to filter user details and the response must be different and not a cached response.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try the framework header addition: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses

Comment: I tried and an error occurs which states that the header() function is not valid (BadMethodCall in ResponseFactory) -   

`return response()->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate')->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));`